# Update data through Vuejs when json file is changed on server (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js

I'm currently learning nodejs and vuejs and stuck on real time updates. I've created API on the backend, which sends data from .json files to frontend. And I want to update data on the frontend in case, some data was changed inside one of those .json files.

I have controller with API logic:

```
module.exports = {
    async index (req, res) {
        try {
            fs.readFile('./src/assets/data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                res.send(data)
            })

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                error: 'an error has occured trying to fetch the quests'
            })
        }
    }
```

And then I'm using it in my router

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/api/main', Controller.index)
}
```

On frontend I'm making request to the API via axios and getting data without issues. But I can't get how to update the data on the webpage if .json file was edited. I was thinking about setinterval, but I guess it's a bad practive to make requests to the server every n seconds. Also tried to handle it with pusher, but failed. And I'm not sure if it's able to track the changes inside file.

Would appreciate any suggestions and help. Thanks!

Comment: Pusher is a good way to listen to change events from the frontend. For the backend consider using a REST(ful) API instead of the blank json-file, this can easily be done with `Express` for `NodeJS`:  https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9

Comment: You can open up a socket with the client and send the file over that way: https://socket.io/. Use fs.watch() to see if the file changed.

Comment: @BennettDams the whole point is that project using specific .json files and not the database or any other option. This behaviour can't be changed